# The magic size of the output file

Tags: imageresizer

I have a short question.

I have one image in two dimensions. 
The first file size is 293KB, the second file is the same file, but passed through the optimizer. 
Its size is 127KB. 
When I use the following parameters: w=370&h=270&mode=crop, I get files with dimensions of 43,8KB and 43.6KB. 
File format jpg, width and height of the images are the same, the library version 3.4.2. 
Only it seems to me very odd that with twice the difference in size, we get the same amount of output. 
I expected that the size of the second file is about 30 KB. 
Can help to understand what is the problem?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both the files had same resolution then cropping them to same width and height will result in near about same file size.

Cropping and Scaling are two different things.

If you want the proportion to be same even after resizing it use scaling instead of cropping.

Comment: Well, let's leave only one option: w=370. Why in this case we output two files with the same size?

Comment: listen you have two same images right?  They have same height and width if i am not wrong. Now you crop them to either same width or same height or both, the dimensions remain same right?   cropping with same dimensions results in same image quality for two pictures which are exactly copy of each other .......  Try changing the dpi for one, then only you will have differently sized file  :-)

Comment: All right, and apparently I don't understand how the converted files. I checked it in Paint.Net and the output of the same file sizes. The issue is closed! Thank you very much!